# Can't delete User Pool Domain when Cognito User Pool already deleted

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-cloudformation

I deployed a CloudFormation template that sets up a Cognito User Pool and an associated User Pool Domain. As there was a misconfiguration in the template a rollback was triggered. The rollback triggered a deletion of the User Pool (successfully) but didn't delete the associated User Pool Domain. As a result, the CloudFormation Stack transitioned into a ROLLBACK_FAILED state.

As the User Pool no longer exists, I was unable to browse to it via the AWS Console. I can confirm that it no longer exists by running the following CLI command:

```
aws cognito-idp list-user-pools --max-results 20
```

Unfortunately, it appears that I am no longer able to delete it via the CLI either as the command requires a reference to the associated User Pool Id.

```
aws cognito-idp describe-user-pool-domain --domain my-domain
```

(Displays error: An error occurred (ResourceNotFoundException) when calling the DescribeUserPoolDomain operation: User pool xyz does not exist.)

```
aws cognito-idp delete-user-pool-domain --user-pool-id xyz --domain my-domain
```

(Displays error: An error occurred (ResourceNotFoundException) when calling the DeleteUserPoolDomain operation: User pool xyz does not exist.)

Is there another way to delete the user pool domain or else clean up orphaned resources in AWS?